# Using multiple views in android

Tags: android, android-layout, view

So I have the following onCreate function

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       mylocation = new MyLocation(this);

       double distance = distance (mylocation.lat, mylocation.lng, messagelat, messagelong);
       Log.d("Distance",Double.toString(distance));
       mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
       mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
       mView = new SampleView(this,Double.toString(distance));
       **this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_clouds);**
       this.button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.close);
       this.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, CameraPreview.class);
             Activity1.this.startActivity(myIntent);
         }
       });

       **setContentView(mView);**

   }
```

My problem is that I want to use both view the one from activity_cloud.xml and the SampleView but If I do it this way I only get the sample view! I want to add a button over and overlay that is implemented in the SampleView class... Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not add the Button from SampleView to activity_cloud directly?

Comment: Why not create a <LinearLayout> in your xml then get the id, and then do something like myLinear.addView(mView)

Comment: I can't add an id to the LinearLayout ? can't imagine why?

Comment: Can't add an id? <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear" /> You mean like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom view within regular xml layouts.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<com.something.something.SampleView
        android:id="@+id/sample_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<Button android:layout_height="0dp"
                                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                   android:layout_weight="1"
                                   android:id="@+id/close"/>
```